# Fixing a damaged stand on a white 20" iMac

Tags: repair

I've been asked to look at an old(ish) 20" white iMac, which was apparently dropped by a courier, and has stopped the stand from holding the screen at a sensible angle. It swings so that it leans as far forward as the stand will permit. It appears that one side is bent or unset and I'd ideally like to fix it. I've tried to remove the stand by sticking my starbucks card (I only needed it for the wifi) into the gap at the top of the stand to get access to the screws, but it seems that the stand is pulled too far back into the case due to the damage to allow proper access.

I'd like to know how much work is involved in getting to the point where the stand attaches to the case. I've already pulled it apart to try to fix an odd ticking noise, which turned out to be a piece of snapped plastic lodge in one of the fans, so I'm not hugely averse to cracking it open again, though if I don't need to, that'd be great. Also if it's a case of pulling the whole thing apart and pulling out all it's guts, then it'd be good to be forewarned.

Anyone any experience of doing this?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would personally complain to the courier and get them / their insurers to pay for a repair.

That being said, if you can't complain to the courier, you can buy just the stand off of eBay or any replacement / spare part shop for about £20-£30, this is probably your best bet to get the best result.

Answer (score 0):

iFixit.com has lots of repair guides for Macs.  I don't see one specifically for replacing the stand but you might find one for replacing something else, that gets you to that on the way.